# Help with SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `plans` table:

```
tariff      |   monthly_cost
--------------------------
  Lion      ,    15.00
  Lion      ,    20.00
  Cat       ,    15.00
  Cat       ,    20.00
  Cat Extra ,    20.00
  Cat Extra ,    30.00
```

to run this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT monthly_cost FROM plans;
```

Which will be:

```
monthly_cost
------------
15.00
20.00
30.00
```

I wanted the result to appear like this:

```
tariff      |   monthly_cost
--------------------------
            ,    15.00
            ,    20.00
  Cat Extra ,    20.00
  Cat Extra ,    30.00
```

How can that be done?

Comment: it's no quite clear, what is the physical sense of such query?

Comment: Could you explain your thinking behind that result? Why should some records be handled differently, and how do you want to determine which records that should be?

Comment: Could you be more precise about what do you want to do with the datas, and why you want this specific output ?

Comment: This is really bizarre. Definitely a design/code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct null, monthly_cost
from plans
where tariff not like 'Cat Extra'
union
select tariff, monthly_cost
from plans
where tariff like 'Cat Extra'
```

Dirty, but efficient.

Comment: Just `select distinct null, monthly_cost`?  Huh?

Comment: Oh, you typed the first line of the answer, submitted it, then editted it?  No +1 for sneakyness...